# Bash script regex

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, bash4

I'm new to bash and I have a question about parsing the output of the command. I have 3 processes that have the same name "process" and the process have some parameters, for example:

```
 process -a 10 -b 20 -c 30 ...
 process -a 15 -b 30 -c 40 ...
 process -a 30 -b 40 -c 50 ...
```

I have to handle the 'a' parameters and assign them to an array if the processes exist. İf they don't exist, I have to restart the process. I am handling the processes with:

```
 `$PS -ef|$GREP -v grep|$GREP process`
```

This gives me the running processes and I have to see which process does not run and restart it with the help of 'a' parameter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: We now know what you want to do, but where's your question?

Comment: @bos. my question is how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `ps -C process -o cmd=` to get a better list of the commands and their arguments.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement). If you're going to abstract `grep` to `$GREP` shouldn't you use `$GREP -v $GREP`? But I agree with Sorpigal.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a wrapper script which would start the process as well as monitor it.

Generic flow will be.

```
var pid_of_bg_process

func start_process
 process -a 10 -b 20 -c 30 ... &
 pid_of_bg_process=$!

start_process    
while true
 sleep 1min
 if file not exists /proc/$pid_of_bg_process
  alert_process_being_restarted
  start_process
 else
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in_array() { for v in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$v" = "$1" ]] && return 0; done; return 1; }

relaunch () {
    echo "Do whatever you need to do in order to run again with $1"
}

watch=(10 15 30)
running=()
while read -r proc a av b bv c cv ; do
    printf 'a was %s, b was %s, c was %s\n' "$av" "$bv" "$cv" # can be omitted
    running=("${running[@]}" "$av")
done < <(ps -C process -o cmd=)

for item in "${watch[@]}" ; do
    in_array "$item" "${running[@]}" || relaunch "$item"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

watcher.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(pgrep -f 'process $1 $2')
[[ -z $pid ]] || wait $pid

echo "process $@: restarted"
process $@
exec $0 $@
```

and start own watcher for each process:

```
nohup ./watcher.sh -a 10 -b 20 -c 30 ... &
nohup ./watcher.sh -a 15 -b 30 -c 40 ... &
nohup ./watcher.sh -a 30 -b 40 -c 50 ... &
```